# What book about OSX internals can you recommend?

Tags: macos, kernel, internals

There's [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321278542/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321278542) but it looks a bit dated. Specificaly, it  talks about bits that are no longer in use (powerpc bootloader for example) on modern machines.

So, my question really is: is there any other book, as comprehensive and detailed as this one?

**EDIT**: There's a new book which seems to be relevant: [Mac OS X Internals - To The Apple's Core](http://www.newosxbook.com/).

Comment: Singh's book is very good. Its a bit dated, but I still frequently reference it. The history is informative. I did not know Apple failed at producing a demand paged memory manager 2 or 3 times (that's why they switched to outsourcing the kernel). I don't know about Levin's book. But I would be surprised if it exceeds Singh's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it's still a great book. The internal hasn't changed that much; once you get the broad idea by reading that book, you can directly go to http://opensource.apple.com/ and read the latest kernel source code without problems.

Comment: That's more or less my concern with that book; how much of that book consists of outdated information, and how much is still useful. I guess I should simply hunt it down on some sale... :)

Comment: Some of the discussion is outdated, but I can definitely say that every page is still useful :) Even the outdated part doesn't give you a wonrg idea what's going on inside, because nothing fundamental hasn't changed.  You need to buy one. You don't regret.

Comment: The changes between say, PowerPC and X86 are confined to relatively small portions of the code, I doubt you would find yourself having trouble navigating the source of modern OSX if you throughly understand prior versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a new book coming out "OS X Internals", the designated sequel to Amit Singh's book:

http://blog.darkrainfall.org/2013/01/os-x-internals/

At the moment it is still in development, but hopefully the "late 2014" deadline will not be pushed back (too much) further!

Comment: That book was apparently half done in March 2016, and the authors promise only that the second half won't take as long as the first. [Source](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/2016_osx_internals_update.html).